# Python and latex

Tags: pdf, compiling, python

Is there any way to compile a .tex to pdf without having to install latex.

Is there any python package for this ?

Or even better is there any small stand-alone portable software for this.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, welcome. I think the answer to this is "no".

Comment: Portable TeX distributions are available (e.g. https://miktex.org/portable) though.

Comment: you can also use online latex systems such as sharelatex https://www.sharelatex.com/ but otherwise your question is equivalent to asking on a python forum how to evaluate a python file without installing python.

Comment: Well theoretically you don't need LaTeX, TeX is enough.

Comment: Why don't you want to install LaTeX?

Comment: If you want to process a latex file it’s helpful to, first, have a computer and, secondly, to install latex.

Comment: @percusse There are student machines in universities with a full installation of python/scipy  (i.e. including matplotlib) but no LaTeX distribution.  I can't understand why either.

Comment: What is your goal?  Did someone send you a .tex file and you need to figure out what's in it?  Are you wanting to create your own documents?

Comment: @Andrew It is possible to run some Windows programs on Linux, via WINE. It is possible to run some Linux programs on Windows 10, without the need for MinGW. So, the question is not completely unreasonable. Also, at least on Windows, some installed programs bring along support files in the same program folder, and the support files may have useful functionality in themselves. For example, many programs contain minimal support from Python. Perl, and Ghostscript, without the need to install those programs.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `matplotlib`, you have a basic [TeX expression parser](https://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#mathtext-tutorial) which works quite well.  But to go beyond that you need to install a (La)TeX distribution.

It *should* be possible to use matplotlib to produce graphics containing equations written in TeX by turning off everything else in the graph and plotting no data.  That would be an interesting question, but one for the python experts rather than for here, assumign you can't figure it out yourself.