# Implementing latex in application

Tags: pdftex, miktex, portability

Is there any way to implement latex in my application(written in python) without having to actually install Miktex or Texlive.

I want to compile a .tex to pdf.

The size should also be small so portable versions cannot be used.

Comment: haven't you already asked this once?

Comment: Which problems do you have with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417543/36296?